# How to apply function to list inside list?

Tags: python, list

I am writing code to sum the second index in a list within a list:

```
employees = [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]

i.e. I want to do 5+3+3= 11

for i in range(len(employees)):
    total_importance = sum(input[i][1])
    or 
    total_important = sum(map(list.append, input[i][1]))

    print(total_importance)
```

Now both of the options above for total_importance produce an error- int object is not itterable or other errors. Is there any way I can amend the code above for it to work?

I have another method where I simply append input[i][1] into a new list and then sum from there, and this easily works. But for my knowledge I want to ask if there is any way to amend either of the code above? Thanks

Comment: To start with, I suggest, instead of doing an addition, you just print out those numbers. You can use the `for` you have and the print statement. You just need to find the syntax to access the numbers you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of pythons powerful unpack features:

```
sum(second for first,second,*rest in employees)
```

This will unpack into three variables, first, second and the rest (in case of uneven lengths).

If you only care to use the second you can use:

```
sum(second for _,second,*_ in employees)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to extract the second element and sum on that new list:

```py
sum([l[1] for l in employees])
```

The above code returns 11 on your employees object.

This also works without creating a new list, by passing a generator to the sum function:

```py
sum(l[1] for l in employees)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider to [reduce](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce) the list to the desired sum

```
reduce((lambda x, y: x+y[1]), employees, 0)
```

EDIT: Please note that input is a [built in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670732/is-input-a-keyword-in-python) in python. In the above mentioned reduce method x represents the "running sum" of summed up elements and y represents an item from the employees list. So x is an int value and y is a list. 0 is the initial value for the calculation:

```
>>> import functools
>>> employees = [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
>>> functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x+y[1]), employees, 0)
11
```

Comment: I get: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1):

The line where you wrote `total_importance = sum(input[i][1])`, inside the sum() you are basically extracting one integer from that list and using sum() on it. This is equivalent to doing `sum(2)` which would of course cause an error.

Instead, you can do

```
total_importance = 0
for i in range(len(employees)):
   num = employees[i][1]
   total_importance += num
```

Comment: I get: `NameError: name 'total_importance' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

So, this is because you are using sum function which works on list. But you are selecting individual element. So you need to do:

```
total_importance += employees[i][1]
```

You can make this code more general like even if the second element is list, it will work.

```
# employees = [[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
employees = [[1, [5,6], [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
total_importance=0
for i in range(len(employees)):
    if isinstance(employees[i][1], list):
        total_importance += sum(employees[i][1])
    else:
        total_importance += employees[i][1]

print(total_importance)
```