# Remove digits between two fullstops

Tags: python, regex, text, python-re, digits

### Is there any way to remove digits between two full stops in python?

eg:

- Input 1: "remove 1 from .1."
- Output 1: "remove 1 from."
- Input 2: "XYZ is a student.2. XYZ is a boy.3. XYZ is smart."
- Output 2: "XYZ is a student. XYZ is a boy. XYZ is smart."

I've tried the following regex but didn't get the preferred output.

```
output = re.sub(r'([^A-Z].[0-9])+)', input)
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\.\d+(?=\.)', '', str)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try doing a replacement on `\s*\.\d+\.` and then just replace with single full stop.

```py
inp = ["remove 1 from .1.", "XYZ is a student.2. XYZ is a boy.3. XYZ is smart."]
output = [re.sub(r'\s*\.\d+\.', '.', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['remove 1 from.', 'XYZ is a student. XYZ is a boy. XYZ is smart.']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few noticeable things in your code.

- Using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) requires 3 arguments, where you have provided 2.
- Avoid [naming your variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670732/is-input-a-keyword-in-python) `input`
- The pattern in your example `([^A-Z].[0-9])+)` is not a valid pattern as there is an unmatched parenthesis at the end.

If you remove that, you have this pattern `[^A-Z].[0-9]` which matches a single char other than A-Z, a dot that matches any character and a digit.

That means that the pattern can match a lot more than than intended.

---

If you don't want to for example change an ip number or a float, you can assert that there is no digit before the match (And note to escape the dot to match it literally)

The pattern is the same as posted by [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) only with a leading negative lookbehind to assert no leading digit.

```
(?<!\d)\s*\.\d+\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vybYy2/1)

Example

```
import re

strings = ["remove 1 from .1.", "XYZ is a student.2. XYZ is a boy.3. XYZ is smart.", "test 127.0.0.1 test"]

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r'(?<!\d)\s*\.\d+\.', '.', s))
```

Output

```
remove 1 from.
XYZ is a student. XYZ is a boy. XYZ is smart.
test 127.0.0.1 test
```